# Anonymous class implementing interface

Tags: c#, interface, anonymous-class

I have the following code inside a method:

```
 var list = new[]
  {
   new { Name = "Red", IsSelected = true },
   new { Name = "Green", IsSelected = false },
   new { Name = "Blue", IsSelected = false },
  };
```

I would like to call a function that requires a list of elements with each element implementing an interface (ISelectable). I know how this is done with normal classes, but in this case I am only trying to fill in some demo data.

**Is it possible to create an anonymous class implementing an interface?**

like this:

```
new { Name = "Red", IsSelected = true } : ISelectable
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

An anonymous type is meant to be a lightweight transport object internally. The instant you require more functionality than the little syntax provides, you must implement it as a normal named type.

Things like inheritance and interface implementations, attributes, methods, properties with code, etc. Not possible.

Answer (score 12):

The open source framework [impromptu-interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) will allow you to effectively do this with a lightweight proxy and the DLR.

```
new { Name = "Red", IsSelected = true}.ActLike<ISelectable>();
```

Comment: This is amazing! I am playing around with it in LINQPad and it works brilliant so far.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could do this, you almost certainly would not want to since a method would know everything about the anonymous class (i.e. there is no encapsulation and also no benefit in accessing things indirectly).

On the other hand, I've thought about how such a feature might look (potentially useful if I want to pass an anonymously typed object to a method expecting a particular interface... or so I thought).

The most minimal syntax for an anonymous type that inherits an interface IFoo would be something like

```
new {IFoo.Bar = 2} // if IFoo.Bar is a property

or

new {IFoo.Bar() = () => do stuff} if IFoo.Bar is a method
```

But this is the simple case where IFoo only has one property or method. Generally, you would have to implement *all* of IFoo's members; including read/write properties and events which is currently not even possible on anonymously typed objects.

Comment: True, that would be neat. 
Maybe specify the interface of the anonymous class like this:
new {IFoo.Bar = 2}:IFoo;